# Return value undefined

Tags: javascript

I am running into some confusion while trying to get an array from a function call.  I am not sure why am getting undefined back instead of the expected value.

The following logs an array as expected.

```
findFraudByFromID = (fraudID) => {
  this.KYCinstance.getPastEvents('ReportedFraud',{
  filter: {fromID: fraudID},
  fromBlock: 0
  }, (error, events) => {
    var frauds = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
      frauds.push(events[i].returnValues.fraudID); 
    }
    console.log(frauds);
  })
} 

trackFraud = (fraudID) => {

  findFraudByFromID.call(this, 1);

}
```

The following logs `undefined`

```
findFraudByFromID = (fraudID) => {
  this.KYCinstance.getPastEvents('ReportedFraud',{
  filter: {fromID: fraudID},
  fromBlock: 0
  }, (error, events) => {
    var frauds = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
      frauds.push(events[i].returnValues.fraudID); 
    }
    return frauds;
  })
} 

trackFraud = (fraudID) => {
  frauds = findFraudByFromID.call(this, 1);
  console.log(frauds);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second case, `return frauds;` actually returns from the callback of `getPastEvents()` as opposed to `findFraudByFromID()`. `findFraudByFromID()` returns nothing, hence the undefined.

Comment: makes sense, how would I go about mitigating that problem?
how can I return the array from the callback?

Comment: See the question that this was marked as duplicate for.

Comment: very helpful duplicate link. thank you